# A little help passwd status on linux

Tags: password

On a linux distro
user mino report this passwd status

```
passw -S mino
mino P 04/21/2015 0 90 15 -1
```

P=passwd ok

04/21/2015 = date creation

0 min pass?

90 max pass valid

15  = ?

-1  = ?

Thanks

Comment: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=passwd+-S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the manual: `man passwd`:

-S, --status
           Display account status information. The status information consists of 7 fields. The first field is the
           user's login name. The second field indicates if the user account has a locked password (L), has no
           password (NP), or has a usable password (P). The third field gives the date of the last password
           change. The next four fields are the minimum age, maximum age, warning period, and inactivity period
           for the password. These ages are expressed in days.

Comment: This doesn't explain password statuses much. What exactly does 'locked password' mean? What is 'usable password'? Can a user log in with a locked password?

Comment: @yentsun A user with a locked password cannot login using password authentication, but is still able to log in using other methods (e.g. an existing SSH key)

Answer (score 2):

Since the content of second field differs on the Amazon Linux AMI (and presumably other CentOS-based distributions) and [passwd(1)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/login/) doesn't document it, I had to go source-diving. The status is displayed by `pwdb_display_status` in [`libuser.c`](https://pagure.io/passwd/blob/master/f/libuser.c), and has six fields:

- `realname` the username (even if the GECOS comment is set)
- `status` one of the following:

  - `NP` empty password (the password hash is a zero-length string)
  - `LK` password locked (the password starts with !, or *x if a different authentication scheme is in use)
  - `PS` password is set
- `date` the date when the passwords was last changed
- `sp_min` the minimum password lifetime in days before it *may* be changed
- `sp_max` the maximum password lifetime in days before it *must* be changed
- `sp_warn` the number of days before the password lifetime expires when the user will start receiving warnings
- `sp_inact` the number of days after the password lifetime expires when the user is disabled (-1 to disable this)
- `msg` a human-readable description of the status

Answer (score 1):

From the [`passwd(1)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html):

> **-S**, **--status**
>
> Display account status information. The status information
>              consists of 7 fields. The first field is the user's login name.
>              The second field indicates if the user account has a locked
>              password (L), has no password (NP), or has a usable password (P).
>              The third field gives the date of the last password change. The
>              next four fields are the minimum age, maximum age, warning
>              period, and inactivity period for the password. These ages are
>              expressed in days.

Comment: `man` pages are not the same for all distros. According to `man passwd` on Fedora and CentOS: __-S, --status__ _This will output a short information about the status of the password for a given account. Available to root user only._

Comment: Indeed, that's why I gave the link to man7.org, which is distribution-agnostic as far as possible.